# how to make radio buttons be one under the other on drupal contact form

Tags: webforms, emails

by default the radio buttons on my drupal contact form come out next to each other and the title is very far from the actual button.

with CSS alone it doesnt work.  I seem to need to be able to edit the html which I cant do since its a drupal form. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26432418/how-to-line-up-radio-buttons-and-text/26432623#26432623

Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome. This is purely CSS question, I'm afraid, and it is totally dependent on the theme you are using. Simply put, you need to find the CSS part that made your radios horizontal and alter it. The rest is totally dependant on your setup.

Comment: Which theme do you use?

Comment: Can you add the html code of the form here so we can help?

Comment: the html is too long.  can I upload it somehow?

Comment: using the omega theme

Comment: Just the portion that has the radio buttons to understand the structure of your code.

Comment: this is related to drupal, because it seems to involve changing the html, which I cant do because its a drupal form http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26432418/how-to-line-up-radio-buttons-and-text/26432623#26432623

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to each of the select button wrapper `display: block;` also it's not a drupal issue, you should ask these kind of question on stackoverflow

Comment: I cant add anything to the select button wrapper since the contact webform doesnt give me the option to modify the html, its created automatically

Comment: you dont have to edit the HTML, each radio button has a class associated with it, inspect the element, find the class and add the style to your CSS file

Comment: I added that, yet the words are coming out under the radios now instead of next to them.  this is what I added .form-radio{
    display: block;
}

Comment: I can't help you anymore than this unless I can see some HTML or a live demonstration of your project